# Can't login into magento 1.8.1.0 on localhost on wamp server using correct username and password

Tags: magento

I have fresh installed magento 1.8.1.0 on localhost with wamp server. Everything has been installed correctly but when i login into the login page with correct username and password it opens the same login page and not get into dashboard page.

I had read a lot of threads saying to make changes in variens.php by opening Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory.

**When i open app/code/core/ i can't find mage folder in core folder.**

Please help how can i fix it?

thank you
kamaldeep singh

---

I don't have the folder mage inside the app/code/core. But i read some thread and made changes  using 127.0.0.1/mymagento/index.php/admin in address bar by editing my C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts it went to dashboard page

And appears error on dashboard

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\mymagento\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 77

i checked classReader.php on line 77 but there is no line related to nesting level to edit.

When i refresh the dashboard page it opens the login page. when i try to login with correct username and password it opens the same login page and no error like invalid username or password.

Comment: Please reply to the comments so that people can help you.Answers given are working for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the Mage folder inside app/code/core your website should not work at all. That folder is essential to run Magento. Check again.

About your problem, do you get any error (wrong username, password, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a customer cant login, or you cant log into the backend, there is an existing issue with customer login depending on the version of magento you might be using.

find : app/design/frontend/(themepackage(/(theme)/template/customer/form/login.phtml

under

```
<ul class=”form-list”>
```

paste in

```
<input type=”hidden” name=”form_key” value=”<? echo Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getFormKey(); ?>” />
```

And in app/design/frontend/(themepackage(/(theme)/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Apply the same changes. 
Clear cache.

Customers should then be able to login.

[Resource](https://www.dwdonline.com/magento-1-8-0-and-1-8-1-customers-cannot-login/)

Answer (score 0):

Does it says that username or password is wrong or only refreshes the page without any error messages? If there are no errors then try to delete cookies for your host and then login again. Usually it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using chrome? If so, try Firefox. Another option might be to use 127.0.0.1/... instead  of localhost/...

Answer (score 0):

In your magento installed folder, go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php And comment out the lines 96 to 112 in v1.9. Lines may differ due to version. Look for lines that looks like this below:

```
// session cookie params
/**     $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );

    if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
        unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
        if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
            unset($cookieParams['secure']);
            if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
                unset($cookieParams['domain']);
            }
        }
    }
**/
```

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem on non FireFox browser(s), use FireFox to execute this action below and try login in with your non FireFox browser(s) again to confirm. I had this issue with Chrome.
Go to `System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management`. And change `Use HTTP Only` from `YES` to `NO`.